# average of array error (worked with int)

Tags: java, arrays, time, runtime-error, average

Beginning to get frustrated here. Self thought noob here. I'm following "java how to program" by John Deitel book, and some pretty random docs that a friend of mine (former CS student) sent me. 
I have written code to calculate averages of `int`s which worked fine.
Then I wanted to test it in `double`s, but keep getting error, even if the "Tool completed successfully" when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.I have since found other people's codes that do the same task, which I kind of understand, but I want know what's wrong with my code.

I have tried setting racecounter to double as well to remove average = **(double)** total / raceCounter;, which resulted in more errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RaceAvgNoNamesDouble
{
   public static void main( String[] args)
   {
      Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );

      double total;
      int raceCounter;
      double racetime;
      double average;

      total = 0;
      raceCounter = 0;

      System.out.print( "Enter race time or -1 calculate: ");
      racetime = input.nextDouble();

      while (racetime != -1)
      {
        total = total + racetime;
        raceCounter = raceCounter + 1;
        System.out.print( "Enter race time or -1 calculate: ");
        racetime = input.nextDouble();
      }

      if ( raceCounter != 0)
      {
        average = (double) total / raceCounter;
        System.out.printf( "\nTotal of the %d races entered %d\n", raceCounter, total );
        System.out.printf( "Race average is %.2f\n", average);
      }
      else
         System.out.println( "No races were entered");
    }
  }
```

Comment: what happens if you change `raceCounter`'s type to double?

Comment: "but keep getting error" / "more errors": what errors?

Comment: same error as if it wasn't assigned as double, putting screenshot into main post now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are making a slight mistake in your first printf statement. As `total` is a double, you should use the `%f` format instead of the `%d` format.

Comment: Perfecto!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
I can't believe it was that simple.
90% of the code I made are all from online/books/forums and with some parts I miss the logic. You have saved me a mouse and monitor, because they were on their way to first floor, from my top floor :D

Comment: You are welcome, please consider accepting this answer so the question can be closed if it helped to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `printf` format `%d` for double, that was the issue, use `%f`, like this:

```
System.out.printf( "\nTotal of the %d races entered %.2f\n", raceCounter, total );
```

For more informations, see [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

---

Also note that the cast in `average = (double) total / raceCounter;` is redundant

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any logical errors except the way you are printing may not work as total is a 'double'. You need to change it to -

> System.out.printf( "\nTotal of the %d races entered %.2f\n",
>   raceCounter, total );